# Using an HttpModule with Application_BeginRequest, how do I check only the first request?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I'm using the following HttpModule to stop a couple of IPs that constantly attempt to spam my contact form.  I don't get the spam as they trigger System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException but I do get the Exception report in my email inbox.  It's not quite as annoying but almost.

I eventually want to test against either a list of IPs from the database or maybe implement the HttpBL api to test against known blacklisted IPs but doing this on every request seems to be overkill.  Either way I do it, whether using IPs in the database or making requests to an external blacklist at every page request surely seems unnecessary.  Can you point me in the direction of checking this once and if the IP passes the test the first time to stop checking?

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace DomainModel.Services
{
    public class BlockIPModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose() {}

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);
        }

        private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            string currentIP = context.Request.UserHostAddress;
            if (!IsIpValid(currentIP))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403; 
            }
        }

        private bool IsIpValid(string checkIP)
        {
            return (checkIP != "213.5.70.205" && checkIP != "188.92.75.82");
        }

    }
}
```

updated code removed - terrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP is stateless, and therefore, you really do have to check each request.  You could cache the blacklist of IP addresses so you don't have to load it each time, but you'll still need to always run *some* test.

If you have control over it, the other option would be to do some filtering on your router.  That would free your code from having to do it.

Comment: I see, but if this IP passes there is no reason to test for it again.  At least not during the current session.  I think caching the result makes more sense than caching the blacklist.  Great idea, thanks!   :)

Comment: This is hosted on a shared server so I don't have access to the router or the IIS controls.

Comment: Each request goes through the same life cycle, regardless of whether a Session was established or not.  Whether you blacklist the IP address at the request level or the `Session`, you'll still be doing the same amount of checks on the server.

Comment: Yes, I see that but I'm not concerned about requests to the server, I'm concerned about unnecessary requests to the database or an external black list.  I have no control over the performance of the external black list if I choose to use it.  Are my concerns unfounded?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("IpResult")` will only give you one value; `Cache` is not a per-session object.  This code will not work.

Comment: When I say you should cache, I mean you should retrieve the blacklist once and store it in memory (maybe in the `Application` object) so that you don't have to call an external black list server for each request.

Comment: Ugh, that's right.  Cache is shared.  The blacklist is huge so I'm not sure I want to store it in memory.  I think I'm not going to rely on an outside source and just keep a personal list of trouble IPs.  Just having a few IPs in a List<> should be much easier to cache and test against.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @mark123, you'd be surprised,.. If we assume that you can store each IP address (assuming IPv4) in four bytes of memory, i.e. with one byte for each octet,.. That's over 262,000 IP addresses per megabyte of memory. How big is the blacklist? =)

Comment: @Rob, that's a good point.  hmmm.  I don't want to cache an external list as it will change.  I just want to cache the result for the current session.  What if I just store a bool flag in Session?  That way if the person is not using an offending IP then they stop getting tested.  Is that a good idea or not?

Comment: You still have to test the bool for each request, so the same amount of testing still has to take place.  Plus, you'd be storing a boolean for each and every session in your app domain.  As @Rob is implying, the blacklist probably isn't too large for you to store in memory (and depending on your user base size, is going to be more memory-efficient than storing a bool in each `Session`)

Comment: @mark123, you're assuming that they pass the session token back so you can associate the request with a given session, just cache the list and refresh it periodically, say every tenth/hundredth/thousandth(choose as appropriate based on the load level you're seeing) time `IpIsValid` is called.

Comment: The blacklist is protected anyway, they don't release the list they just let you test against it.  Back to square one.

Comment: @mark123 - if the list check is a slow/expensive (time and/or money) operation if the IP address check returns true, *cache* the IP address and always check your local cache first. There's always options =)

Comment: I don't understand why the same amount of testing would have to be done.  If the positive result is saved (in session or otherwise) the testing against a blacklist is not performed at all.  Only the test to see if the saved result exists.  In 1000 requests 1000 tests for the existence of the result happen and if none of them exist then 1000 test happen for the IP.  That's 2000 tests.  If all of them have the result already then 0 tests for the IP occur.  That's 1000 tests.

Comment: @mark123, what I'm saying is that you always having to test each request (checking for a bool flag is still a test).  You just have to choose the most efficient way to perform the test.

Comment: Gotcha.  :)  Checking a bool has got to be quicker than making a request to an external database though, right?  Even under the best circumstances.

Comment: Yes.  I'd use @Rob's suggestion where you cache results per IP address rather than caching per `Session`.  If you could get the entire blacklist, though, it'd be more efficient to store that in an in-memory `HashSet` and use that to look up the IP address of each request.